# Send command to another user's screen terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen

I have two users; user1 and user2.
I have a bash script run by user1, that needs to run a command on a screen terminal started by user2.
Suggestions?
Thanks
Max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Do you want it to look as if *user2* typed the command?

In the case of `screen`, you can use

```
screen -S user2/sessionname -p windowname -X stuff "~user1/somescript.sh
"
```

This will type the text `~user1/somescript.sh` (referring to a file in user1's home directory) to a specific window of the given screen session and send a newline character.

(Yes, the second `"` must be in a new line, otherwise you would just send the text and have to press return in the screen session. Alternatively, use `$'stuff blah\n'`)

To do this, you will need to have write access to `user2/sessionname`; read screen's manual page for description of `multiuser` and `acladd`.

---

In the generic "run stuff on another tty" case, you can use `writevt /dev/pts/X sometext`; the `writevt` tool is part of *console-tools* package. If your distro uses *kbd* instead, get [`writevt.c`](https://raw.github.com/grawity/code/master/thirdparty/writevt.c). This is specific to Linux.

### Or do you just want user2 to see the *output*?

```
./somescript.sh >& /dev/pts/X
```

where `/dev/pts/X` is the tty device that belongs to user2's screen.

You will need write access; this can be given by user2 with chmod/setfacl, or you can use `sudo`.

(`>& file` is equivalent to `> file 2>&1`, which redirects both stdout and stderr to the given file.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer; to clarify, I need to accomplish the first goal (look as if user2 typed the command).  What is the difference between screenname, and windowname?  I looked through the man page for screen, but couldn't find anything.
Thanks

Comment: @mazzzzz: A user may have multiple 'screen' sessions (I think I should have used *sessionname* rather than *screenname*). Each session can have multiple windows. (Having multiple windows displayed in a tiled layout is common: C-a `:split`)

Comment: And if you only have one window, what would its name be?  Does it have a default name, or do I need to find it somewhere?

Comment: @mazzzzz: Just skip the -p option.

Comment: Don't know if this is the best practice, but it works :)   
Start the webhost user, then run a screen in there, then su into the server user, then run the server.  Haha, there is something wrong with that.  Thanks for the help (and if you have a better way to set it up, I'm all ears)

Comment: @mazzzzz: Best practice is to *not* run a server in `screen` unless you have a really good reason for it. (What server is it?)

Comment: It is a game server (minecraft), can't (or I haven't found a way to) run it in the background.